# Can't get output of LVM commands on Centos 7

Tags: centos

It is my Centos 7 server and I can't get any output when I run LVM commands. Can someone help me to understand, what can I do to fix it?
This server was powered-off moved to new location and powered-on.

```
[root@centos-db ~]# lvscan
[root@centos-db ~]# vgs
[root@centos-db ~]# pvs
[root@centos-db ~]# lvs
[root@centos-db ~]# lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM    SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   14.9G  0 disk
└─sda1            8:1    0    976M  0 part /boot
sdb               8:16   0      1T  0 disk
└─sdb2            8:18   0 1023.1G  0 part
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0     50G  0 lvm  /
  └─centos-swap 253:1    0     16G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
[root@centos-db ~]# lvmdiskscan -v
    Wiping cache of LVM-capable devices
  /dev/centos/root [      50.00 GiB]
  /dev/sda1        [     976.00 MiB]
  /dev/centos/swap [      16.00 GiB]
  /dev/sdb2        [    1023.07 GiB] LVM physical volume
  2 disks
  1 partition
  0 LVM physical volume whole disks
  1 LVM physical volume
[root@centos-db ~]# vgdisplay -v
    No volume groups found.
[root@centos-db ~]# df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G   15G   36G  30% /
devtmpfs                  94G     0   94G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     94G   88K   94G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     94G  9.6M   94G   1% /run
tmpfs                     94G     0   94G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                945M  264M  632M  30% /boot
tmpfs                     19G   16K   19G   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                     19G     0   19G   0% /run/user/0
[root@centos-db ~]#
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I did `obtain_device_list_from_udev = 0` and `use_lvmetad = 0` in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` and rebooted, and then I was able to see LVM commands and also I was able to see `/home`, which was missing earlier.